Why do I get a blank screen after upgrade headers+
I havent tried this (update/upgrade) for a while so the details below are all I have.
I am using Ubuntu 22.04 as a mail server with iRedMail and Roundcube (with postfix and dovecot). Everything is working fine!
I can update packages but the items below are kept back.
Usually I would do a "sudo apt-get install" and install the items. But every time I try, the server no longer boots. I just get a blank screen with no login as user text, or prompt for password.
Any ideas how to fix this?
Im not a developer at all really. Here's the kept back items when I do update followed by "sudo apt-get upgrade".
The following packages have been kept back:
  linux-headers-generic linux-headers-virtual linux-image-virtual
  linux-virtual python3-update-manager ubuntu-advantage-tools
  ubuntu-pro-client-l10n update-manager-core
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.

So, when I run:
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic linux-headers-virtual linux-image-virtual linux-virtual python3-update-manager ubuntu-advantage-tools ubuntu-pro-client-l10n update-manager-core

The server wont let me login after the upgrade.
It just boots and the kvm/ssh is blank.
Any help appreciated, thanks.
ADDITION: I just tried to upgrade again and it recommended some things. Then when I tried to upgrade again everything went fine. Im pretty sure its all upgraded now. I'll just leave it a day and a few restarts to be sure before creating a snapshot.
